# What do the logical functions IMP and EQV do in VB6? Has anyone found a real world use for them?

Tags: vb6, boolean-logic

[`And`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242751(v=vs.60).aspx), [`Or`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242850(v=vs.60).aspx), [`Xor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242859(v=vs.60).aspx) and [`Not`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242842(v=vs.60).aspx) I understand. What I don't get are [`Imp`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242794(v=vs.60).aspx) and [`Eqv`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242780(v=vs.60).aspx). What do they mean? How'd they get in there? Is there any real use for them?

Comment: You could add some linkage to the VB6 reference manual topics for IMP and EQV. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242794(VS.60).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242780(VS.60).aspx

Answer (score 17, accepted):

IMP is "material implication" "a implies b" or "if a then b", which is equivalent to NOT a OR b.  EQV is "equivalence" or "if and only if", so a EQV b is the same as (a IMP b) AND (b IMP a).

They got there because someone wanted to be complete.  They can shorten some logical expressions, but you can always express the same thing with NOT and AND, NOT and OR, or with XOR alone.

Comment: +1. You could add some linkage to the VB6 reference manual topics on IMP and EQV. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242794(VS.60).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242780(VS.60).aspx

Comment: I *could*, but that would mean finding them.  Ick.  Thanks for doing so yourself,.

Comment: Is `EQV` not the same as `=`?

Comment: Effectively yes, but EQV is the name as a boolean operation.

Comment: Look like `Imp` is "If a Then b Else True" and `Eqv` is "Not Xor"

Comment: I would like to give this answer two upvotes for its clarity.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the truth table for all the operators, both for boolean and for bitwise. The best time to use them is when you map your logic and realize you have a function that takes two inputs, and has the same outputs as those operators:)

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|AND  |     |     |     |OR   |     |     |     |XOR  |     |     |     |IMP  |     |     |     |EQV  |     |     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|In1  |In2  |Out1 |     |In1  |In2  |Out1 |     |In1  |In2  |Out1 |     |In1  |In2  |Out1 |     |In1  |In2  |Out1 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|False|False|False|     |False|False|False|     |False|False|False|     |False|False|True |     |False|False|True |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|False|True |False|     |False|True |True |     |False|True |True |     |False|True |True |     |False|True |False|
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|False|Null |False|     |False|Null |Null |     |False|Null |Null |     |False|Null |True |     |False|Null |Null |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|True |False|False|     |True |False|True |     |True |False|True |     |True |False|False|     |True |False|False|
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|True |True |True |     |True |True |True |     |True |True |False|     |True |True |True |     |True |True |True |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|True |Null |Null |     |True |Null |True |     |True |Null |Null |     |True |Null |Null |     |True |Null |Null |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Null |False|False|     |Null |False|Null |     |Null |False|Null |     |Null |False|Null |     |Null |False|Null |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Null |True |Null |     |Null |True |True |     |Null |True |Null |     |Null |True |True |     |Null |True |Null |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Null |Null |Null |     |Null |Null |Null |     |Null |Null |Null |     |Null |Null |Null |     |Null |Null |Null |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|In1  |In2  |Out1 |     |In1  |In2  |Out1 |     |In1  |In2  |Out1 |     |In1  |In2  |Out1 |     |In1  |In2  |Out1 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|001  |001  |001  |     |001  |001  |001  |     |001  |001  |000  |     |001  |001  |111  |     |001  |001  |111  |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|001  |010  |000  |     |001  |010  |011  |     |001  |010  |011  |     |001  |010  |110  |     |001  |010  |100  |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|001  |011  |001  |     |001  |011  |011  |     |001  |011  |010  |     |001  |011  |111  |     |001  |011  |101  |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|001  |100  |000  |     |001  |100  |101  |     |001  |100  |101  |     |001  |100  |110  |     |001  |100  |010  |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|010  |001  |000  |     |010  |001  |011  |     |010  |001  |011  |     |010  |001  |101  |     |010  |001  |100  |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|010  |010  |010  |     |010  |010  |010  |     |010  |010  |000  |     |010  |010  |111  |     |010  |010  |111  |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|010  |011  |010  |     |010  |011  |011  |     |010  |011  |001  |     |010  |011  |111  |     |010  |011  |110  |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|010  |100  |000  |     |010  |100  |110  |     |010  |100  |110  |     |010  |100  |101  |     |010  |100  |001  |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|011  |001  |001  |     |011  |001  |011  |     |011  |001  |010  |     |011  |001  |101  |     |011  |001  |101  |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|011  |010  |010  |     |011  |010  |011  |     |011  |010  |001  |     |011  |010  |110  |     |011  |010  |110  |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|011  |011  |011  |     |011  |011  |011  |     |011  |011  |000  |     |011  |011  |111  |     |011  |011  |111  |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|011  |100  |000  |     |011  |100  |111  |     |011  |100  |111  |     |011  |100  |100  |     |011  |100  |000  |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, they both perform a bitwise !XOR on the two inputs and return the result.

They are not present in any of the .Net code base (unless you count the VB6 compatibility layer library) so should be considered deprecated and therefor ignored.

Off the top of my head I can't say as I've ever used them.